# Does burning something with higher temperature make the burning faster?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, physical-chemistry, combustion

Like if I burn wood at 500 C, or 1000 C, is there a relationship? Any equation that model this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Burning faster* could be understood in different ways. Here are a few comments:

**Rate of chemical reaction**
Being a chemical reaction, [combustion rate usually obeys the Arrhenius equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_kinetics#Temperature):
$$k=Ae^{-E_a/RT},$$
that is the reaction goes faster at higher temperatures, which help to break the reactant molecules.

**Speed of flame propagation**
[Laminar flame speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laminar_flame_speed) gives the speed with which the flame front propagates along the mixture of the unburned reactants. It also increases with temperature:
$$s\propto\sqrt{\frac{T_b-T_i}{T_i-T_u}},$$
where $T_b, T_u$ and $T_i$ are the temperatures of the burned and unberned reactants and the ignition temperature.

**Adiabatic flame temperature**
[Adiabatic flame temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combustion#Temperature) characterizes the completeness of combustion process (i.e., how fully the reagents are used). It also increases with the reagents temperature:

> The adiabatic combustion temperature (also known as the adiabatic flame temperature) increases for higher heating values and inlet air and fuel temperatures and for stoichiometric air ratios approaching one.

Comment: Arrhenius equation works for a homogenous mixture of reactants, but "if I burn wood," is a _process_ that has more variables than just the temperature. In fact, OP did not even specify "temperature of _what?_" One could argue that there is no such thing as "wood at 500C or 1000C." If you put wood in a vessel, deprive it of oxygen, and apply heat, then by the time everything reaches 500C, the only solid matter in the vessel will be charcoal.

Comment: @SolomonSlow indeed, the question is not very specific... and neither is my answer.

Comment: @RogerVadim Yep I'm actually looking for limits on how fast a substance can burn. I'm thinking of a bag of trash that has multiple and unknown elements. Thank you for your help